# Compiling expression in html in AngularJS controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I bind html from the AngularJS controller and display this information in Bootstraps `$uibModal` like so:

```
$scope.phoneNumber = '0111111111';

var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
    template: '<div class="modal-header d-flex flex-column align-items-center justify-content-center">\
                    <p class="font-h3 font-weight-medium">Please contact us on {{phoneNumber}}</p>                     

                </div>',
    appendTo: undefined,
    controllerAs: '$ctrl',
    controller: ['$uibModalInstance', '$timeout', '$state', function($uibModalInstance, $timeout, $state){

        //LOGIC GOES HERE

   }]
});
```

When the modal displays, the static text displays, but the expressions aren't compiling.

**Question**

How do I get the expression to compile in the controller before displaying to user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add 'resolve' to your modalInstance with what you want to send to the modal controller. After that you need to pass it in as a dependency to the modal.

```
$scope.phoneNumber = '0111111111';

var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
    template: '<div class="modal-header d-flex flex-column align-items-center justify-content-center">\
                    <p class="font-h3 font-weight-medium">Please contact us on {{$ctrl.phoneNumber}}</p>                     
               </div>',
    appendTo: undefined,
    controllerAs: '$ctrl',
    resolve: {
    phone: function () {
        return $scope.phoneNumber;
      }
    },
    controller: ['$uibModalInstance', '$timeout', '$state', 'phone', function($uibModalInstance, $timeout, $state, phone){

        //LOGIC GOES HERE
        this.phoneNumber = phone;
   }]
});
```